# Eevee Intel integrated graphics GPU

Tags: eevee-render-engine, gpu

I recently got a new laptop, and I want to use it to animate in Blender. It has Intel Iris XE Integrated Graphics. I understand that OpenCL and OpenGL are no longer supported for cycles rendering, but I want to use Eevee **to render. NOT run.**

Is there a way to use Iris XE graphics with Eevee. It does support OpenGL so I would suppose so. Would it work by default or would I have to change some variable? Would this functionality continue to new blender versions?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a resounding YES! Eevee is the way to go with Intel GPUs. Sad that I can't use Cycles, but it isn't the end of the world.

When testing I figured out that while rendering with eevee, the GPU performance was at 100%.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

[List of supported GPUs](https://code.blender.org/2019/04/supported-gpus-in-blender-2-80/)

It looks like Haswell was Gen7, and Iris XE is Gen12, so it should be fine.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Intel_graphics_processing_units

Comment: Thank you for your time. This answer is not complete. That page is NOT for rendering in Blender, just running it.

Comment: Since Blender is free and you already have the laptop, I recommend you try and give a self-answer to this Q

Comment: An excellent idea, I don't currently have access, but If this question isn't answered when I do I will for sure. Thanks for the suggestion.